# AWS RDS connection string

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform, amazon-rds

I have a question.

So I am trying to automate my RDS connection string with terraform, but the database identifier is randomly generated per region in each aws account.

Is it possible to know before hand the database identifier? and if so i there a way i can automate it?

Below is my current scripts:

`sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:5432,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:env0.**cvhjdfmcu7ed**.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`

I current i'm using this below script to feed in variables to terraform in my ***userdata tpl*** file

`sudo nohup socat TCP-LISTEN:${port},reuseaddr,forkTCP4:${name}.${connection}.${aws_region}.rds.amazonaws.com:${port}`

If some here can suggests ways that i can use to automate the `${connection}` variable, so that i can deploy it in any aws account and region and don't have to worry what possibly the identifier would be.

Comment: The connection endpoint is available in the `Endpoint.Address` [attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#aws-properties-rds-database-instance-return-values) of the created RDS instance. No doubt, Terraform provides a way to get this value (in CloudFormation you'd use the GetAtt intrinsic function).

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `endpoint` attribute available in either the [aws_db_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance) or [aws_rds_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster) Terraform resource to access the `hostname:port` RDS endpoint in Terraform.

If you are not creating/managing the RDS instance in the same Terraform where you need access to the endpoint address, then you would use the appropriate Terraform `datasource` instead of a Terraform `resource`, which would lookup the RDS information and make the endpoint value available within the rest of your Terraform template.

Comment: Mark B, thanks for your response, will the data lookup look like this?

Comment: ```data "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.name
  endpoint = "address:port"
}```

then reference it like so?

connection = data.aws_db_instance.database.endpoint

Comment: no you wouldn't have `endpoint` in the lookup. You would just look it up based on the values you have, and then reference the endpoint afterwards, like `data.aws_db_instance.database.endpoint`

Comment: Thanks so much it worked, happy holidays